# Ruby on rails and HAML - Print a hash with background color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a Hash.
my_hash = { "name": "aaa", "age":"28 [previous value: 27]"}
I found the difference between two hashes and stored it in the above format. 
Now I need to print the Hash like this:

name    aaa

age     28 [previous value: 27]

But I want the background of the line containing the age value(ie the value which contains the term "previous value") highlighted in green.
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
- my_hash.keys.each do |key|
  %p= key
  %p.highlighted-hash= my_hash[key]
```

And then you just need to add highlighted-hash to your stylesheet

```
.highlighted-hash {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

#00FF00 is a hex value for green - you could change that up, obviously.

Or I suppose you could put the style inline:

```
- my_hash.keys.each do |key|
  %p= key
  %p{ style: 'background-color: #00FF00;' }
    my_hash[key]
```

But I would prefer something more like the first.

Comment: I can print the hash but the background color for the lines are still not changing.

Comment: I'm sorry - read that wrong... missed the part where you were looking for *just* the age value to have the background... edited my answer.